# What is stored in variable cols in : var $cols = $('.sortdivs').on('click',function(){...});

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $cols = $('.sortdivs').on('click',function(){…});
```

I know that the function will run when any element with sortdivs class is clicked.
I dont know what is being stored in variable cols and how it can be used.
I tried printing variable cols and i got 'object Object' as the output.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the list of all DOM elements wrapped in jQuery object, which can be used to call jQuery methods on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value from `.on` is simply the collection that it was called on, for chaining purposes.

`$cols`, therefore, is the jQuery object containing a list of elements matched by `$('.sortdivs')` at the time of exection (NB: not at the time of click).

`[object Object]` is the string representation of any object. Try to inspect the object in another manner, for instance by using `console.log($cols)` to be able to get more information of just the output of a simple `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see access all the property store in variable by writing $cols[0] like ATTRIBUTE_NODE,canHaveChildren, canHaveHTML etc. You can debug and see what is inside $col[0] and based on your requirement you can manipulate them. I hope this will be helpful for you.